# How to resolve relocation warning L6437W using ARM DS?

Tags: assembly, arm

I am working on some startup code for a Cortex-R5. The code compiles, links, and runs without a problem. However, I am getting the following warning.

```
Warning: L6437W: Relocation #REL:7 in startup.o(VECTORS) with respect to my_symbol. Branch relocation to untyped symbol in object startup.o, target state unknown.
```

That code calls a `bl` to `my_symbol` which contains about 90 or so instructions and a `bx lr` to return.

The created ROM is not large (~30K) and the entry is in the HIVEC (0xFFFF_0000). I looked for the warning in the [ARM Compiler Errors and Warnings Reference Guide Version 5.06u1](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0496/m/Linker-Errors-and-Warnings/List-of-the-armlink-error-and-warning-messages). The text is not very helpful and contains a typo.

From the Reference Guide:

```
L6437W:Relocation #<rel_class>:<idx> in <objname>(<secname>) with respect to <armsym>. Branch relocation to untyped symol in object <armobjname>, target state unknown.
```

Any help here would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi @yqbear, I have a similar issue. Can you please share your solution for me. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I would have said that the error message is fairly clear.  Whatever tool created the object file containing the symbol my_symbol did not set the type of the symbol, so the linker has to guess whether the instruction set at the destination of the symbol is arm (32 bit instructions) or thumb (16 bit instructions) in order to preform a relocation to it.

The fact that everything works means that it guessed correctly, but if you want to eliminate the warning then you will need to edit the question to say which tool created the object containing the symbol.

Comment: Thank you. That gives me some more to go on. Some of this is new to me so the warning is not obvious. The tools are armclang and armlink. The options call out `-mcpu=cortex-r5` and `-marm`. The instructions all look like arm and no thumb so I'm still stuck. I do have work arounds, but would like to understand the warning. I can remove warnings by rearranging the code to remove the `bl` and `bx lr` instructions. I can also change the `bl my_symbol` to a `ldr, r0, =my_symbol` and a `blx r0` to remove the warning. In the last case, both jump to the same place and the Thumb T bit is never set.

Comment: Hi, I meant mainly is the target symbol in assembly or C/C++?  The C compiler should set the correct type of symbol.  If it is in assembly then there are directives that you can put to mark it.  Eg: I use GNU assembler and I put `.thumb_func` before my symbols.

Comment: Hi @TomV, Can you help me please. I have a same issue: I have a symbol ```brsStartupHyp``` and define of that is  ```void brsStartupHyp(void);```` but why it is raise error. Thank you